# Modifying Parent Attribute Value from Child in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, parent-child, key-value-coding

I have following parent child relationship between two entites

[image]

In my scenario i have to update a parent attribute when some change occurs to child attribute.

```
    + (void)updateTaskStatus:(Task *)task
          withTaskStatus:(NSNumber *)taskStatus
  inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    [task setValue:taskStatus forKey:@"taskCompletionStatus"];
    [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"taskSyncStatus"];
    [task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"list.listSyncStatus"];
}
```

but this line from above method

```
[task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"list.listSyncStatus"];
```

produces following error

`the entity Task is not key value coding-compliant for the key "list.listSyncStatus".'`

So my question why is this happening? If this is not the way then what would be the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"list.listSyncStatus"` is not a *key*, but a *key path* (with two keys), therefore:

```
[task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKeyPath:@"list.listSyncStatus"];
```

Alternatively, use the property accessor methods and write

```
task.list.listSyncStatus = @NO;
```

if you have generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses for your entities.

Comment: @Wain list object exist. Answer did the job.

Comment: @Wain You don't need to check to see if it exists since Objective-C is `nil` tolerant.  Calling a setter on `nil` doesn't produce an error.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra true indeed, I meant that you might get 'unexpected' results (some people assume that it can just be set immediately).